# Do I need to hide my base64 in app purchase public key? and how do I do that?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Is the base64 public key I use for in app purchases something I should obfuscate in some way? and how would I do it if that was the case?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/how-dangerous-might-be-publishing-a-public-key

Comment: Sure I understand it is public so it's ok, but I'm thinking more of those people who download your apk, and then do string replaces and republish the app (maybe that isn't happening anymore). Basically, should I be doing something to make it more difficult for those people to replace my in app public key with theirs so they get sales on the cloned app they made?

Comment: I guess `ProGuard` is the only thing that you can do additionally to this. Or make a remote server that would return your public key on-demand (but in this case, you're facing the same problem as someone might crack your app and change the server which points to). Basically if someone wants to break it, it will, but I guess that's where the app signature does its job (and also a little bit of users' common sense).

Comment: Thats not how public and private set of keys work...do some google research.